# show face detected with open CV C++ with new window

Tags: c++, opencv

I am wondring how can I use 2 windows in order to show:

1. captureCAM
2. the face captured

Answer (score 0):

Each window you create with openCV has a string name in cvCreateWindow
To draw in that window call cvShowImage with the name of that window as a parameter.

Take a look at the examples in the openCV download, or the openCV book